# How to integrate Bugsense into a 8.1 universal app

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, bugsense

Does anyone know, how to integrate Bugsense into a Windows (Phone) 8.1 universal app? I've installed the Bugsense.WP81 package via NuGet in my project, but I can't integrate it like Bugsense at WP8. When I try to open the official [docs](https://www.bugsense.com/releases/windowsphone/3.6.6.0) from bugsense.com, i've get an error.

thanks in advance,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was my fault. You should add the BugSense package on both Windows and Windows Phone.

```
public App()
{
    BugSenseHandler.Instance.InitAndStartSession(new ExceptionManager(Current), "App-Key");
}
```